# Could not update last-build.bin

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, android-studio

When i build my app with react-native CLI, it give me this error FAILURE:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not update android/.gradle/8.0.1/fileChanges/last-build.bin
```

I run  the ./grandew clean but happen the same error

Answer (score -1):

okay i think you should try your luck by down Android Gradle Plugin Version 8.0.1 to 7.3.0 and gradle version to 7.4 i am not sure :/